# how to save my recharts to a html file with R

Tags: r

below is my code to get a rechart:

```
recharts.emap <- eMap(df,namevar=1,datavar=2,title=title)
```

when I run the code below:`recharts.emap`
It runs well and create the Interactive picture:[image: the Interactice pic that I get]

now, I want to know how to save the the Interactive picture into a HTML file! I got a method before`htmlwidgets::saveWidget(recharts.emap,file=ofile)`,but it faild.Look forward to you answer.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [RMarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com). I tried a sample dataset `mapTestData_chs`.

Here is what I did.

````
```{r}
library(recharts)
mapData <- head(mapTestData_chs, 5)
eMap(mapData, namevar=~stdName, datavar = ~val1 + val2)
```
````

This is called a chunk. You can find the result below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! but when I used Rmarkdown,I finded another problem. When I knit the .Rmd file into HTML, it told me that count not find the function that I wrote in another .R file. I wonder know if the .Rmd file count not call the function which is defined in anthon .R file. By the way, I am a student  and I have never touch the R .And I am trying to do my assignment with R accoring to my teacher's requirement.

Comment: If you want include the function, you can use the `source` function in R to instruct R to read from your desired file, the function you want to use.